# compress image on upload in angular

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript, base64

I wanted to upload images to products, and users. So im converting the image to base64 string and sending it. But when the selected image is large, the image is not getting uploaded as the base64 string is too large.

Here is the code:

Html

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
<button  type="submit" title="upload" (click)="uploadImage()"></button>
```

TS File

```
onFileSelected(event){
var files = event.target.files;
var file = files[0];
if (files && file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload =this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
}
_handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
this.base64textString= btoa(binaryString);
console.log(btoa(binaryString));
}
```

Im just accepting the images on selection. So, is there any way to comress the image after selection or a way to reduce the base64 string so the image gets uploaded.
Thanks!! in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can upload image wihtout converting it into base64. Check this...

```
import { ViewChild }            from '@angular/core';

export class yourComponent { 

    @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;
    .
    .
    .
}

uploadImage(){
    let fileBrowser = this.fileInput.nativeElement;
    if (fileBrowser.files && fileBrowser.files[0]) {

        console.log(fileBrowser.files[0]);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("userId", this.userId );            //appending userId in formData
        formData.append("image", fileBrowser.files[0]);     //appending image in formData
        this.apiService.UploadImageMethod(formData)
        .subscribe(
            response=>{
                console.log(response);
                if(response.status == 'success'){
                    console.log(response);
                } 
            },
            err  => {
                this.imageErrorMsg = <any>err.message;
                console.log(this.imageErrorMsg);
            }
        );          
    }
}

HTML:
<input type="file" id="fileInput" (click)="hideErrorMsg()" accept="image/*" #fileInput>
```

In API, you can get image data this way. (Php)

```
UploadImageMethod(){
    $fileName   = request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $ext        = strtolower(request()->image->getClientOriginalExtension());
}
```

Good Luck!!!